# "could not have been him" vs "could have not been him"

Tags: negation, subjunctives

Say a huge rock rolled down from a cliff and killed a passenger by the window of a passing-by bus which I was on. HOWEVER, before the rock hit the bus, I had switched seats with the poor man, the victim.

So I can say :

> a.It could be me
>   b.It could have been me
>   c.It could not have been him
>   d.It could have not been him

Which is correct and why, please?

Answer (score 1):

All of these are grammatically correct.  In the situation you describe, talking about an ["twist of fate"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/twist-of-fate), the most common expression would be:

> That **could have been** me.

In this case the present perfect expresses a potential *life experience*, narrowly avoided.

However, the negative of this generally means simple lack of *ability* or *potential*, and not *fate*:

> Larry **could not have been** (or simply *could not be*) the one who robbed that bank yesterday.  He's on vacation in Belize.

Instead you would use a conditional:

> If he hadn't switched seats with me, it **would not have been** him (who died that day).

or, alternately:

> If we hadn't switched seats it **would have been** me (who died that day).

Comment: Is the "d" correct? The "not" after the second modal not the first one?

Comment: @mvlog option c expresses an impossibility, option d expresses the possibility of a negative. it's the same as "it is possible that it was not him. "

Comment: @Hellion Right, and as your example goes, the "d" should be put as _It could **have been not** him_ . And look at [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+have+not+been%2C+could+not+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20have%20not%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20have%20been%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @MvLog  the ngram is erroneous.  Hellion's comment is that it's possible to say "It could have **not** been him" as a response to a previous comment about what the various possibilities are.  The two sentences ("It could not have been him", "It could have not been him") imply different things.

Comment: @Andrew I don't ask about "c" and "d". I do ask about "d". What's the difference between _It could have been not him_ and _It could have not been him_?

Comment: @MvLog   I can't imagine a context where "It could have been not him" would make sense.

Comment: @Andrew  _John was killed yesterday. It could have been not him, had he stayed in that house with us. But he didn't._

Comment: @MvLog There's no way I would ever intentionally say that.  I would instead he "he wouldn't have been killed, had he ..."

Comment: Thanks for your help. By Example c. and d., I wanted to express the meaning of "It could have been someone else instead of him". I see your solution is to add an "if" clause and use "would not have been him". Does it mean it is wrong or not idiomatic to use "could not have been him" or "could have not been him" under the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Under all of those possibilities, in correct, "formal" English (English almost never spoken, but grammatically correct), it should read:

"It could have been **I**."

It would also be "I" instead of "me" for every one of your examples and, in the answer above, it should read:

"It could have been *he* (not him) who died that day."

This is an example of the "predicate nominative" in English.  Most English speakers say things such as "It's me" or "It's him or us", but correct English (formal English used especially in writing) would say "It is I" or "It is he or we".  For instance:

"It is *I* who *am* to blame."

"It is *we* who *have* to live on this planet so it is *we* who *must* protect it."

"It is *they* who *are* the reason that we have failed."

"It is *she* whom you want."

Again, this is very formal English; therefore, I am teaching you the English that you would use when you are writing a formal essay, paper, dissertation, treatise, etc. in English.  This would almost never be heard in Modern English conversation, however, wherein the "disjunctive pronoun", which is in the oblique case, is always used in colloquial speech.  Sigh, it is not *I* who *write* the rules. (Notice the subject-verb agreement between "I" and "write".)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, though it is a little beside my question.